Получение строкового имени класса в рантайме Java
Есть функция которая принимает тип данных(не знаю как точно называется)
И нужно для определенных манипуляций получить название класса. 
Вот пример кода.
public class SomeClass {
    

    public <T> String getClassName() {
        return /*тут надо получить название класса T*/; 
    }

    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        System.out.println(getClassName<String>());
    }

}


И вобще как называется запись типа <T>

Ответ на подвопрос: как называется запись типа  здесь: Что значит <T> перед возвращаемым типом в методе.  Также см. Можно ли определить generics тип класса

В функцию можно передать класс и получить его название:
class SomeClass {
    public String getClassName(Class<?> c) {
        return c.getTypeName();
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        System.out.println(new SomeClass().getClassName(String.class));
    }
}

Вернет: java.lang.String
Получить названия типа через T нельзя, можно получить класс объекта, который присвоен полю с типом T, например:
class SomeClass<T> {
    T type;

    SomeClass(T type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return type.getClass().getTypeName();
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        System.out.println(new SomeClass<>("SomeObject").getClassName());
    }
}


Понятно.Но было бы удобно если можно было бы.
Спасибо за ответ.
